# while bool variable is true I want to display CurcularProgressIndicator() for some duration, but its not showing in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

//This is the Class of one of my app page (MainPage)

It has showindicator() function which is turning _isloader into true for 10 seconds.

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool _isloader = false;
  
Future<void> showindicator() async {
    _isloader = true;
    print("_isloader before $_isloader");
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    print("_isloader after$_isloader");
    _isloader = false;
    Get.to(PersonalAssessment());
    print("_isloader afteroperation$_isloader");
  }
```

//This the Main Widget Build function

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MyColors.backgrey,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    top: 20,
                  ),
                  child: GlowGlass(
                    Customheight: 200,
                    Customwidth: double.maxFinite,
                    Firstcolor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.8),
                    Secondcolor: MyColors.Primarypurple.withOpacity(.4),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 250,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    top: 20,
                  ),
                  child: CarouselSlider(
                      items: Appconstants.mainimages
                          .map(
                            (e) => Container(
                              height: 200,
                              width: double.maxFinite,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                // color: MyColors.Primarypurple,

                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  image: AssetImage(
                                    e,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                      options: CarouselOptions(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        autoPlay: true,
                        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                        viewportFraction: 1,
                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                  child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 230,
                  left: 10,
                  right: 10,
                ),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 400,
                    width: 400,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
```

//here I wrapped Widgets into GestureDetector, so when I tap
showindicator() runs _isloader turn to true for 10 seconds and for 10 seconds CircularProgressIndicator() displays on screen but unfortunately its not showing on screen although showindicator() works perfectly.

```
                              GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                showindicator();
Center(child: 
CircularProgressIndicator());                            
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 200,
                                    width: 360,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          blurRadius: 10,
                                        )
                                      ],
                                      color: MyColors.backgrey,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                          height: 170,
                                          width: 150,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                color: MyColors.Primarypurple,
                                                blurRadius: 10,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                            // color: Colors.blue,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                            ),
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              image: AssetImage(
                                                  "lib/Assets/images/dekstop.PNG"),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your CircularProgressIndicator()? There is currently a lot of code and widgets that does not relate to the problem. It's easier to us to help you if you remove all the unnecessary code.

Comment: Does the UI get updated after showindicator()? Have you tried setState()?

Comment: Thanks for yout respone, Mala there's a reason to show whole class with widget trees because there's possibility that any other widget is obsecuring Circularprogressindicator(),It can be helpful to undersatnd.

Comment: Yes, I checked with setState() and without it nothing happened

Comment: I wrapped some widgets to gesturedetector and calling showindicator() and CircularProgressIndicator(),  GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                showindicator();
                               Center(child: 
                               CircularProgressIndicator());                            
                              },

Comment: That's not a correct way to add a widget to the widget tree. To add CircularProgressIndicator() to the widget tree it has to be some other widgets child.